# iOS high ping time

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, networking, ping

I have iPhone, iPad and Mac in wirless network. Ping time for router and Mac is around 1-5ms. But ping time for iOS devices is around 100ms, sometimes more. Why? Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: What are you pinging, how are you pinging/measuring, etc?

Comment: @Enthusiast : Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

If your mac and routers are connected through wires then its useless to compare the wire connection with wireless connection.

Wired connections are more faster and even depends on the wireless connection bandwidth.